# Snowmelt erosion in USLE?

Tags: soil, snow, erosion

Is there any way to compute snow-melt erosion with Universal Soil Loss Equation? How can I change rainfall erosivity factor to snow-melt erosivity?

Comment: See `Jiri Brychta's` work as an example https://www.researchgate.net/publication/337567801_Calculation_of_average_annual_soil_loss_in_nongrowing_period_for_South-Moravian_region_using_USLE-GIS_method